# Unable to call function from another Python file

Tags: python

I have `Workflow.py` file containing following function:

```
class Workflow:
    def Validation(self):
        return print ("Validation Process Started..")
```

I have another file `Cron.py`.

```
import schedule
import time
from Workflow import Validation

class Cron:

    def my_job(self):
        print('Foo')
        Workflow.Validation()

    def Start(self):
        schedule.every(2).to(4).seconds.do(self.my_job)
        while 1:
            schedule.run_pending()
            time.sleep(1)

A = Cron()
A.Start()
```

I am trying to call `Validation()` function present in `Workflow.py` from `Cron.py` file. Both of these files are places in same folder. But, the code is giving following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "cron.py", line 3, in <module>
 from Workflow import Validation
 ImportError: cannot import name 'Validation'
```

Please can anyone help on resolving this error.

Comment: I think you are looking for `from Workflow import Workflow` which should fix it

Comment: `Validation` is not a top level function. It's a class method. Change your import to `from Workflow import Workflow`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `Workflow` class inside of a `Workflow` file which is why you're confused. There is no `Validation` to import, because `Validation` is inside of the class (and not the file)

The correct way would be:

```
from Workflow import Workflow
```

And then you could call it like this:

```
Workflow.Validation()
```

However, please note that this function is not a class method or a static method as it is defined right now. If that's how you want to call it, it should look like this:

```
class Workflow:
    @staticmethod
    def Validation():
        return print ("Validation Process Started..")
```

In general if your method doesn't use `self` or `cls` inside of it, it should be a static method

Comment: plus one for mentioning the class/static method issue

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
import Workflow
flow = Workflow.Workflow()
flow.Validate()
```

ps. you should read about static methods, or avoid using classes unecessarily

Comment: @OferSadan right, thanks! yeah I admit I answered it without putting through an interpreter :-|